# Meaning of "sat out in front"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> The judge rapped. “Objection sustained.”
>
> The next question came like an explosion through the close air of the courtroom. “Mrs. Lee, did you see the accident in which your husband met his death?”
>
> The woman nodded yes. Her reply was lost in the sudden stir and scuffling as people moved forward.      “Tell the court what you saw.”
>
> “Well,” said Esther Lee, “Joseph had gone to Union. He drove there everyday because he had good customers there. **I sat out in front**, always, to watch for him. I always used to do that, when he fished at Barnegat_” Archie Stolt’s lawyer was on his feet, but the prosecutor motioned him into his chair. “Tell only about the accident, please,” he said to Esther Lee.
>
> Esther Lee’s blue eyes were wet. “I watched Joseph’s old car come around a bend in the road,” she said slowly, “and he was on the right side of the road. And then the red car came from the other way- on the wrong side of the road. And-Joseph’s car swung out toward the middle-to try and miss it, I guess. But the other car swung out, too…. They hit. That’s all, sir. But the red car was on the wrong side of...”

I want to know the meaning of "sat out in front". Dose it mean: I waited and watched him from far distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sit out front [of a building or structure]. Usually, in a car or vehicle but could also be on a bench too or other structure **in front of something**. But we don't know how far away from the structure the person was in the story.

This is confusing because there is Union Beach, a town in Jersey, and Barnegat on Long Island, NY and in New Jersey.

Union Beach, NJ is on the "Jersey shore" and there is a Barnegat Light House there and there is also Barnegat Bay on Long Island, in New York state.

However, I think here it is referring to the Jersey Shore due to the word Union. '
It's funny because I know these places pretty well......

Here is the lighthouse, at Ocean Beach, New Jersey, the Barnegut Lighthouse State Par. [Barnegut Lighthouse](https://www.state.nj.us/dep/parksandforests/parks/barnlig.html)

Comment: It is clear from the [context](http://treeofknowledge.tripod.com/variety/blue_eyes_away.html) that Mrs. Lee  "sat out in front" of her home on Watchung Mountain watching for her husband's return from Union through a telescope, as she had done formerly when he was a fisherman and they lived in Barnegat.

Comment: @StoneyB you should post that as an answer

Comment: @PaulDexter Lambie has already answered OP's question; I'm merely resolving the ancillary puzzle of location.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, right. Good.  The OP should have posted the question with a little bit more context. These types of questions get old, fast. Having to constantly tell them to provide context.